# UIImageView will not resize to match UIView's frame

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, cgrect

I want my background to be an image, so in IB I set a `UIImageView` with the constraints to be the same size as the its `UIView`. However, when I select "`back`" on the `UINavigationBar`, when the `NavControl` pops to the previous `VC`, this is what's there, briefly, before it disappears: [image]

That is, the `UIImageView` is so big that it is almost double the width of the UIView, so as it slides off-screen to the right, the `UIImageView`'s image drags on before finally disappearing.

I have also tried to do this programmatically, but even if I set the `UIImageView`'s frame to be `CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)`, it still goes off to the left side of the `UIView`, as if the `UIView`'s origin weren't at the top left corner, but slightly off the screen. Is this possible? How do I make it so the image fits the screen and doesn't go off?

If it's at all relevant, the `jpg` I'm using is in `Images.xcassets` and, although I can select it in IB and it appears, the `UIImageView`'s image is white/blank, so in my `viewDidLoad` method I need to specify self.imageView.image = `[UIImage imageNamed:@"hockeyIce.jpg"]`.

Comment: check the constraint?

Answer (score 1):

1. go to **Main.storyboard**
2. select the **view** in question
3. click **Attributes Inspector**
4. scroll down to **View**, select **Mode: Scale To Fill**

Comment: OK, so that did actually work. But the image looks much better in its native aspects. Is there no way to make it AspectFill without it going offscreen? Is it something to do with Hugging or Compression Priorities?

Comment: Ahh, I solved it. I needed to add this to `viewDidLoad`: `[self.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES]`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the solution was to add `[self.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES]` to my `viewDidLoad`. It turns out that this is a common problem with aspectFill.